# update a dynamic variable using function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters, arguments

Hi I need help in coding a javascript
i want to change a dynamic variable using a function, my code is like this

```
var a=0;
var b=0;

function UpdateValue(Variable,x)

    {
       Variable=x;

    }

UpdateValue(a,2);
UpdateValue(b,3);

console.log("a: ", a); //returns a: 0
console.log("b: ", b); //returns b: 0
```

I always get 0 result. the variable does not update
what's the proper code for my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work because primitives are **passed by value** in javascript. So if you pass as a parameter, changing it in a function won't affect to passed parameter.

> You should use **arrays** or **objects** because they are **passed by reference**.

Like bellow

```
var a=[0];
var b=[0];

function UpdateValue(Variable,x)

    {
       Variable[0]=x;

    }

UpdateValue(a,2);
UpdateValue(b,3);

console.log("a: ", a); //prints a: [2]
console.log("b: ", b); //prints b: [3]
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response.. The example above is helpful. Can you give me example using an Object?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Arguments in functions will refer to same values as arguments in the function call; there is no way for the function to redefine a variable in the caller. You can change the variable *contents*, if a variable is an object (or an array).

You should rethink why you need to reassign an outer-context variable in an inner context. This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).